# Ionic animation for splash screen

Tags: javascript, mobile, cross-platform, ionic-framework

Is it possible to add gif or svg animation as a splash screen for Ionic Mobile App? I couldn't find any solution but it looks like a typical task. Maybe I missed the solution.

```
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"  />
  <feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
  </feature>
  <gap:splash src="img/splash.gif" />
  <gap:splash src="img/splash.gif" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
```

If I put .png it works, but .png doesn't support animations.

Answer (score 4):

It is mentioned in the document that the only supported files are: png, psd, and ai.

[Ionic Icon SplashScreen](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html)

If you want to customize, try this one it might help you:

[Using Views Events To Create JavaScript Pure Ionic Splash Screen](http://www.gajotres.net/using-views-events-to-create-javascript-pure-ionic-splash-screen/)